# Merge databases psql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, merge

I am working with postgreSQL.

Suppose you have a database A. You make a dump of it and from this create a copy B. You add some information in the tables of A and other information in the tables of B.

At some point you need the information stored in A also in B. Is there a way to merge A into B?

Comment: You can write queries that Merge the data from one table to another. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql

Comment: To execute a query from one database from another you have to access it like this SELECT Columns FROM [ServerName].[databaseName].[schema].[TableName] If they are on different servers, you will need to create a linked server.

Answer (score 0):

I do this fairly frequently to synchronize lookup values across databases.  Here are three approaches you might consider:

1. Script the data additions, so that the script can be run on multiple databases.  This may or may not be feasible depending on the environment and mechanism by which the original updates take place.  If this is a frequently-occurring process, save the new additions in a table or file and write the script to read updates from that data source.
2. Use a foreign data wrapper (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/postgres-fdw.html) to connect the two databases, and write a query to pull data from one to the other.
3. Use execsql.py (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/execsql) instead of psql, connect to both database, and use the COPY or COPY QUERY metacommand to copy data from one database to the other.

Disclaimer: I wrote execsql.py.  Nevertheless, I favor approach #1 for regularly-occurring updates.